# How to enable/disable cameras' effects programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a main camera in my scene with a Sun Shafts (Script) ImageEffect on it.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

(I'm using Medieval Environment asset.)

I'd like to disable this effect programmatically when main camera reaches a specific coordinate.

> > > Please kkep in mind, that the script I'd like to disable is a .js script.

So here is my code:

```
foreach(Camera c in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) 
{
    if ((c.name == "Main Camera"))
    {
        if ((c.transform.position.x < -10))
        {
        //Disable Sun Shafts effect
        }
    }
}
```

How to disable Sun Shafts effect programmatically?

Comment: Just an unrelated comment, Fract. You should not be using unityscript. It's only realistic to use c# these days. Forget unityscript and try c# (it's actually easier, anyway).

Comment: Why are you saying `private ImageEffects mySunShaft;` and not simply `private SunShafts mySunShaft;`? Was SunShafts derived from some ImageEffects component?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because THIS IS NOT A TUTORIAL SITE, WHERE NOVICE HOBBYIST PROGRAMMERS CAN GO BACK AND FORE BEING TUTORED IN THE MOST BASIC SKILLS.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yet you chose to encourage more such questions by answering it?

Comment: @Bart: Tried "private SunShafts mySunShaft;" as well. It drops following exception:
"Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SunShafts' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp)"

Comment: You simply can't *change questions by editing them* here, so I rolled it back (as someone should have done straight away).  Do not hesitate to ASK NEW QUESTIONS, you're allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google "Unity3d disable a component" you will instantly find the answer

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enabling-disabling-components

```
yourComponent.enabled = false;
```

For example this flawless answer by one of the best Unity engineers, is basically perfect

http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/26849/view.html

Note for example *"If you see a checkbox in the Inspector, you can enable or disable it."*

Note that here on StackOverflow you cannot **change questions by editing them** -- don't hesitate to ask new questions.  Ask as many as you wish.

Comment: The edit gives the answer, as does this answer. What is the problem you're still facing? If you don't understand the code provided, it's probably best to pick up a good book on C# and learn about some of the basics of the language.

Comment: The example in the edited section uses a script called "Light" so the code looks like this:  "private Light myLight;"
However I do not use "Light" but a script called "SunShafts.js" which displays in Unity as "Sun Shafts (Script)".
I've tried to change the code above (change "Light" to "SunShaft") however the compiler fails with errors. Why?
How to change the code to make it work with Sun Shafts as well?

Comment: How did you actually change your code, and what are the errors you get when doing so?

Comment: Please see Edit #2.
The error I get: "The type or namespace name SunShaft could not be found..."

Comment: If it says exactly that, make sure you've written `SunShafts` (plural) because that from your screenshot seems to be the actual name.

Comment: I've doublechecked (and corrected the code part in my original comment): I use "SunShafts" everywhere in my code.
The issue remains: "The type or namespace name SunShaft could not be found..."

Comment: @JoeBlow: QUIT SHOUTING AT PEOPLE. Also, the phrase you're looking for is "back and forth".

Comment: @Joe Blow: I will immediately accept your answer once you update your answer with a working code section. Sorry, I cannot do anything with your 
"theoritcal answer".
Your answer is not an answer for .js scripts. Please answer why 
"private SunShafts mySunShaft;" 
drops following exception: "Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SunShafts' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (Assembly-CSharp)"?

Please keep in mind, that I'm working on a C# code and I'm trying to handle a .js script within the C# code.
This is not a novice job.

Comment: you realise you need something along the lines `using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;`

Comment: did you think to google "unity3d SunShafts code"  example http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/754418/modify-sunshafts-from-c.html

Comment: you realise this is a Pro-license only feature btw?

Comment: Ah, StandardAssets live in their own namespace now? I was unaware of that. Never use them really :D